# Contact-Form PHP

Tags: php, contact-form

i have an Contact Form on my Website. And every new Form that are send by the Website comes to my E-Mail contact@xx.com.
Now i have a problem. My contact form always uses form@xx.com as the sender of the e-mail and not the e-mail of the person who filled out the contact form.

My Contact.html with the contact form :

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class='input-group-addon'>
            <i class='fa fa-envelope-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
            id="E-Mail1523703412" 
            name="fields[E-Mail]" 
            placeholder="" 
            data-rule-required="true"
            data-msg-required="This field is required." data-rule-email="true" data-msg-email="Invalid email." 
            style=""/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
```

My Contact Script :

```
$email_sent = mail("contact@xx.com", $subject, nl2br($body), "From: form@xx.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");

if( $email_sent ){
$output = array("success" => 1, 
                    "redirect" => 0, 
                    "msg" => "Email sent successfully.",
                    "data" => $data
                );
echo json_encode($output);
            exit;
    } else {$output = array("success" => 0, 
                    "error" => "Email error",
                    "msg" => "Something went wrong, please try again.",
                    "data" => $data
                );
}
?>
```

I think i must change the form@xx.com in the script file but i don't know whic variable i must use.

Comment: Well you clearly know how to get the `$subject` and `$body`, just use the same method to get the email from the form. Surely?

Answer (score 0):

The wild and woolly days of sending email using someone else's address are over, due to spam, etc.

Still have the `from:` being your `forms@` email.  Set the `reply-to` email to be the person who provided their address, and you can set a from name to their name.  This way you can search by name, and when you hit reply you reply to the submitter.

Here's how I set my headers

```
    <?php

    $userName="ivanivan";

    $userEmail="ivanivan@example.com";

    $email_recipient="m.martin@example.com";

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$userName." <forms@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$userName." <".$userEmail.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: php-form2mail-example.com";

    $subject="Demo Message";

    $message_body="This is a demo message";

    mail($email_recipient, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    ?>
```